# How to render item views for a collection including an add new view?

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I don't understand why the DOM is not updated in the collection view render:

```
class FastTodo.Views.TodoItemsIndex extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['todo_items/index']

  el: '#main'

  render: ->
    $(@el).html @form_view.render()
    @collection.each @renderOne

  renderOne: (item) ->
    console.log(@)
    console.log(@el)
    $(@el).append "model data"

  initialize: ->
    @collection = new FastTodo.Collections.TodoItems()
    @form_view = new FastTodo.Views.AddTodoItem collection: @collection
    @collection.bind 'reset', =>
      @render()
    @collection.on 'add', (item) =>
      @renderOne(item)
    @collection.fetch()
```

The idea is that #main first get a view with add new form, and then the collection is appended to #main.

How would I do this?

The output of the view in the console looks like: [image: populated collection is not rendered]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) For `@collection.each @renderOne` to work correctly you need to bind your `renderOne` method to the view instance like this: `renderOne: (item) =>` (notice the fat arrow), because otherwise it is invoked in the global context (that's why you see these `Window` objects in your console.

2) DOM element, not the view itself, should be inserted into DOM, so `$(@el).html @form_view.render()` should be written as `@$el.html @form_view.render().el` (the `render` method should return the view instance according to the backbone community convention).

Other looks fine and it should work this way.

You may wish to refer to some posting about context in js to deeper understand the subject ([this one](http://joshuakehn.com/2011/10/20/Understanding-JavaScript-Context.html) for example).

btw you can write less code for some things. i.e. this

```
@collection.bind 'reset', =>
  @render()
@collection.on 'add', (item) =>
  @renderOne(item)
```

can become this

```
@collection.on 'reset', @render
@collection.on 'add', @renderOne
```

but you should remember to bind your `render` method with the fat arrow in this case.

Comment: thanks! the context bindings with coffeescript are a lot clearer now